# C Program automatically rounds

Tags: c, rounding

EDIT: Problem has been solved, I will try to make it as clear as possible now though.

When I was making a program to calculate the area of a circle, I assigned "3.1415926535" to a constant float Pi. When I used it in my program as areaCircle = Pi * radius * radius, where radius was an integer and areaCircle was a float, the program printed out something like "7.000000". I had expected it to return a decimal such as "7.123456" or something

EDIT: This is the code, if you guys need it:

```
int radius
float circumference,areaCircle;
const int PI = 3.14159265358979323846264338327;
printf("Enter the radius of the circle: \n");
scanf("%d",&radius);
circumference = PI*2*radius;
areaCircle = PI*radius*radius;
printf("The circumference of a circle with radius %d is %f and its area is %f\n",radius,circumference,areaCircle);
```

Comment: OK, so what's the problem? What's the question?

Comment: That's too bad. If you want us to show you *why* this happened, you will need to provide the code you compiled and executed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You mind creating a [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: `const int PI = 3.14159265358979323846264338327;` Here PI is `int` but `3.14159265358979323846264338327` is a `double`

Comment: For now, please declare all your variables as `double`.  No `float`, no `int`.  (You will need to adjust your printf and scanf formats to match.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you posted you have declared `PI` as an `int`. Try:

```
const float PI = 3.14159265358979323846264338327;
```

Comment: Probably prefer `double` to `float` in general (I know Daniel used `float` in their question, so this applies there as well), because they give more precision, are pretty much just as cheap time-wise on most modern floating-point units, and while they take up more space, for most applications space isn't an issue.

Comment: @Muzer: Most floating point implementations, even on modern CPUs don't support double precision or have to use (possibly partial) software-emulation for it. That's because far by most CPUs are in embedded systems and have single-precision FPUs **at best**.

Comment: OK, point taken, didn't consider this might be a question for embedded devices.

Comment: @Muzer: I don't think so either. But your statement about "most modern ..." is wrong. And C is indeed used mostly for such systems or kernel programming which (like Linux) might also disallow using the FPU.

Comment: Although note that I said "most modern floating-point units". I'd argue that embedded systems probably don't have FPUs, so my statement is strictly correct (even if misleading) ;). And the microcontrollers with FPUs I'd have thought would support double-precision well.

Comment: @Muzer: Alone the Cortex-M4F should outnumber x86, possibly even Cortex-A. That device is clearly a modern CPU and has a FPU with **single** precision only. Similar for other embedded CPUs. "embedded" does not imply "no FPU" today. It's not just 8051.

Answer (score 0):

> It'll be very nice if you make your question more clearly.

Though I have Some Suggestion ...

- Your program shows `areaCircle Value as floating data` , Because, areaCircle is float. And it is calculating a float number also.
- `Logically` -Radius `can't be Integer` type.
- You can set `all data types as float / double`.
- And can also use this into statement to 
  control digits after decimal point  `%.2f` or `%.0f` or any value you need.

Comment: The *only* variable in the code which is the "wrong" type is `PI`. Everything else works, apart from possible arithmetic overflow when calculating area and perimeter (which can happen with any variable type).

Comment: you may use cos(-1) instead of pi :)

Comment: I think you mean `acos(-1)`.

Comment: ` ow ,, yess :) `